# Weird crash on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I just uploading my app to a device for the first time and it crashed. It doesnt crash on the iOS Simulator, but it does on the actual device,

This is the error i get:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000C2C)
8.24-bit little-endian signed integer, deinterleaved 
2012-08-20 21:27:50.242 OGLGame[11058:707] ( 0   CoreFoundation                  
0x30f588a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186 1   libobjc.A.dylib            
0x36029259 objc_exception_throw + 32 2   CoreFoundation               
0x30f58789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 0 3   CoreFoundation        
0x30f587ab +[NSException raise:format:] + 34 4   CoreFoundation       
0x30ec568b -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 234 5   OGLGame    
0x0009bce7 -[SingletonSoundManager loadBackgroundMusicWithKey:fileName:fileExt:] + 130 6   OGLGame       
0x00095df5 -[EAGLView initGame] + 816 7   OGLGame                     
0x00095a05 -[EAGLView initWithCoder:] + 1156 8   UIKit                
0x318f2c13 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 218 9   UIKit           
0x31961b1b UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1778 10  UIKit          
0x31961423 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 90 11  UIKit         
0x318f2839 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 152 12  UIKit      
0x31961b1b UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1778 13  UIKit          
0x319616bb UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 658 14  UIKit           
0x31961423 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 90 15  UIKit         
0x318f1fc5 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 664 16  UIKit     
0x318f3861 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 136 17  UIKit                          
0x31829385 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 36 18 UIKit
0x316b26eb -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 222 19  UIKit                               
0x316ac72f -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 234 20  UIKit
0x3167aac3 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1010 21  UIKit 
0x3167a567 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 54 22  UIKit                 
0x31679f3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826 23  GraphicsServices      
0x312ee22b PurpleEventCallback + 882 24  CoreFoundation               
0x30f2c523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38 25  CoreFoundation                      
0x30f2c4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140 26  CoreFoundation                      
0x30f2b313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370 27  CoreFoundation                   
0x30eae4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300 28  CoreFoundation              
0x30eae36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 29  UIKit                         
0x316ab86b -[UIApplication _run] + 550 30  UIKit                      
0x316a8cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080 31  OGLGame                       
0x00095475 main + 168 32  OGLGame                            
0x000953c8 start + 40 )
```

Does anyone know where this crash is being caused?

Thank You.

Comment: It would help us a lot if you could provide the exception text rather than just the stack trace. The problem appears to be related to inserting a value into a dictionary in `loadBackgroundMusicWithKey:fileName:fileExt:`.

Comment: i think app is crashing at appdidfinishlaunching method in appdelegate itself.. try breakpoint there and check where exactly app is crashing

Comment: So do you know a way to solve it?

Comment: We can't fix the code you didn't post. All you've given is a stack trace.  At a minimum post the method: SingletonSoundManager loadBackgroundMusicWithKey:fileName:fileExt: